# Where can I get GEoIP lookup as good as adultFriendfinder

Tags: geolocation

Firstly, I am not sure if this question is better suited for Programmer.se, or here. If it's a better fit for Programmer.se, please migrate it over there.

I am working on a website targeted towards users in India, and I would like to get their city, based on their IP address.  I have tried several IP lookup services and databases ( both free and paid) and I havent really got good results in my tests.

I was wondering how adultfriendfinder (I am sure you have seen their ads on most porn sites) manages to get the user's location so accurately.

I would be willing to pay for this kind of accurate service.
Do any of you know which service or database adultfriendFinder uses?

*EDIT*

I have tried MaxMind, and it has been accurate only for about 55% of my samples. Google is worse than that, coming at a rate of 40%. AdultFriendfinder comes in at a respectable 85%.

Comment: hahahahhahaha, love the reference to adultfriendfinder

Comment: Camel-case too...  It's too bad domains aren't case sensitive, or you could easily find other programmers that way.  adultFriendFinder.com  Bahahaha

Comment: Since this is the one I hear about the most, I trust you've tried it- http://www.maxmind.com/app/lookup_city

Comment: Have you seen http://msteigerwalt.com/articles/2008/07/18/SpecialFriends